# Correct way to commit/push to subtree repo?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm writing code for the two side of a hardware connection. Each end has its own repo, and I have a third repo that contains the interface protocol. Then I place that Protocol repo as a subtree in the two repos for each end of the link. To me this seems to be the best way to do this. (interested to hear other approaches)

I have implemented the above but I'm still not clear on how to commit/push code changes. I have found some tutorials that have been helpful, but this part is not clear to me.

If I make changes to the subtree that I want to commmit/push (so I can pull it down into the subtree in the other repo), what are the correct sequence commands? I know to do:

```
git subtree push --prefix=my/folder subtree_origin master
```

but how do I do the "add" and "commit" steps of the normal process?

Changes to the upper repo (non-subtree) I expect to just do as normal, correct?

Comment: Subtrees are integrated into the main repository. Unlike submodules, there is only one repository and you do everything in the repository. With one repo there is only one way to commit. :-)

Comment: Thanks, so do I just do 'git add' --> 'git commit' --> 'git push' AND 'git subtree push'?

Comment: Yep, exactly. `git subtree push` 1st does `git subtree split` so it's a kind of automatic submodule — commits in the subtree to be pushed are collected in a separate branch.